Does executing a child workflow in Temporal puts a message on to the child queue?
In Temporal, when a child workflow is executed from a parent workflow with its own configuration (where a different queue is configured for child workflow), does that "also" put a new message on to the queue that the child workflow is configured for? Or does it only start the child workflow, waiting for a message to be posted on to the queue so the corresponding worker can pick it up? Any relevant Temporal documentation would be greatly appreciated.
